# Temporarily remove access to execute function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a project where I on a website display content users can "interact" with using keypress W or P. Doing this, the site executes a function posting to a php writing to a mysql-database. However, if the key is pressed and HOLD or pressed multiple times in a row - I get multiple setTimeouts running and crap happens. **How can I temporarily remove access to running (or disable) the keypress-functions when executed once?**

```
<html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jkey-1.2.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css">
        <script>

$(function content(){
var reloading = function(data){
      $.ajax({                                      
      url: 'api.php',                        
      data: "",                      
      dataType: 'json',                     
      success: function(data)          
      {
        var id = data[0];              
          _id = id;
        var vname = data[1];           
        var message = data[2]; 
        var field1 = data[3]; 
        _field1 = field1;
        var field2 = data[4];
        _field2 = field2;
        var ans1 = data[5];
        _ans1 = ans1;
        var ans2 = data[6];
        _ans2 = ans2;
        var val1 = parseInt(ans1, 10) ;
        _val1 = val1;
        var val2 = parseInt(ans2, 10) ;
        _val2 = val2;

        $('#output').hide().html( message ).fadeIn("slow");   
         $('#username').hide().html( "@"+vname +":" ).fadeIn("slow");
         $('#valg1').hide().html( field1  ).fadeIn("slow");
         $('#valg2').hide().html( field2  ).fadeIn("slow");
     window["reload_timer"] =  setTimeout(reloading,6000);
 }
      });
  }
    reloading();

  $(document).jkey('p',function() {
     $.post("update.php", { "id": _id} )
      $('#output').hide().html( "<i>Thx!</i>< ).fadeIn("slow");
      $('#username').fadeOut("fast");
      $('#valg1').fadeOut("fast");
      $('#valg2').fadeOut("fast");
        clearTimeout(window["reload_timer"]);
         setTimeout(reloading,5000);
      });
        $(document).jkey('w',function() {
     $.post("update.php", { "id2": _id} )
      $('#output').hide().html( "<i>Thx!</i>< ).fadeIn("slow");
      $('#username').fadeOut("fast");
      $('#valg1').fadeOut("fast");
      $('#valg2').fadeOut("fast");
        clearTimeout(window["reload_timer"]);
         setTimeout(reloading,5000);
      });
      }); 
</script>

</head>
  <body><div id="container">
      <div id="username">
</div>
  <div id="output"></div>
  <div id="posted"></div>
     <div id="field1"></div>
<div id="valg1"></div>
       <div id="valg2"></div>
       </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Introduce a variable called e.g. `blocked`:

```
var blocked = false;
```

In the key handlers, abort if blocked and set blocked to true otherwise:

```
$(document).jkey('w',function() {
    if(blocked) return; // abort
    blocked = true; // disallow any further key presses
```

Unblock in the success handler of `reloading`:

```
success: function() {
    blocked = false; // allow again
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a flag and check it in your two keypress handlers:

```
var allowKeyPress = true;

$(document).jkey('p',function() {
   if (!allowKeyPress)
      return;

   allowKeyPress = false;

   // your existing code here
}
```

Somewhere else in your code you then set `allowKeyPress = true;` again - I'm not sure exactly where you want to do that: perhaps within your `reloading()` function, perhaps in the success callback from your `$.ajax()` (in which case really you should add an error or complete handler to reset the flag if the ajax call fails), or perhaps just with a new, separate `setTimeout()`.